# How to create NSMutableArray using NSPredicate from the NSMutableArray/NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have NSMutable array which contains certain fields in its index as a key and value pair like this

```
Result =     (
            {
        FName = @"Achal";
        MName = @"Pradip";
        LName = @"Gandhi";
        AGE =  35;
    },
    {
        FName = @"Jenish";
        MName = @"Pavan";
        LName = @"Patel";
        AGE = 40;
    }
    {
        FName = @"Pritesh";
        MName = @"Amit";
        LName = @"Dave";
        AGE = 50;
    }
    {
        FName = @"Mehul";
        MName = @"Nikhil";
        LName = @"Shah";
        AGE = 40;
    }
);
```

From that array i want to filter it and i need out put **Using NSPredicate** like this

```
FilterArray = {
        FName = @"Achal";
        LName = @"Gandhi";
    },
    {
        FName = @"Jenish";
        LName = @"Patel";
    }
    {
        FName = @"Pritesh";
        LName = @"Dave";
    }
    {
        FName = @"Mehul";
        LName = @"Shah";
    }
);
```

Only "FName" & "LName" keys are Required from the original array.

Comment: use your array like as array of dictionary , thats all, where ever you need use that key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made solution with this below code and its perfectly work.

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for(int i=0;i < self.Result.count;i++){
    NSMutableDictionary *cartData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [cartData setObject:[[Result objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Fname"] forKey:@"FName"];


    [cartData setObject:[[Result objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"LName"] forKey:@"LName"];

    [tempArray addObject:cartData];
}
```

But this is done by a loop but i want to use and solve it with the help of **NSPredicate** .

Answer (score 1):

NSPrecate returns a list of objects filtered by one or more conditions.
In your case, you want to get some array but with different objects.
You can use this code :

```
NSMutableArray *FilterArray =[NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSDictionary *dic in Result){
        NSDictionary *newdic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dic objectForKey:@"FName"],@"FName",[dic objectForKey:@"LName"],@"LName", nil];
        [FilterArray addObject:newdic];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get desire output result array without using `NSPredicate`

here is the Small code snippet

```
NSArray *arrObjects = [responseObject valueForKey:@"Result"];

[arrObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *_Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    [arrFilterResult addObject:@{@"FName":[obj valueForKey:@"FName"],@"LName":[obj valueForKey:@"LName"]}];
}];
```

if you have any problem , let me know.